# Will knocked-out soldiers in dumpsters and toilets ever wake up?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In previous Metal Gear games, I recall that unconscious enemies that are put in lockers would never wake up; they would remain unconscious indefinitely.

Is the same still true of enemies in The Phantom Pain? Will enemies put in dumpsters and toilets ever wake up, either on their own or by having another enemy check the container?

Comment: Well, it's a simple enough experiment to run. Throw a guy to the ground, stuff him in a dumpster, and start smoking cigars.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sleeping or stunned enemies will remain in toilets and dumpsters indefinitely.

The only way that they will woken is if you take them out, or if another enemy happens to check (specifically a toilet) as part of an alert clearing.

Comment: You could also put them into a vehicle to achieve the same effect, though they would be more easily spotted by other sentries.